# Is there a good way to do this type of mining?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-mining

I am trying to find points that are closest in space in X and Y directions (sample dataset given at the end) and am looking to see if there are smarter approaches to do this than my trivial (and untested) approach. The plot of these points in space looks something like the following and am trying to find sets of points marked inside the boxes i.e. the output I am looking for is a set of groups:

```
Group 1: (1,23), (2,23), (3,23)...
Group 2: (68,200), (68,201), (68,203), (68,204), (68,100), (68,101), (68,101)...
```

[image]

For the horizontal bands, I am thinking I could just go ahead and use small sliding windows of size say, 5 or 10 (which should really be determined from the global information of which size will give the maximum grouped points but I am still exploring a good approach) and search for contiguous points because a break would not be considered a horizontal band anymore.

I am guessing the same approach works for the vertical bands as well but not in all cases because there is a subtle difference in horizontal and vertical bands: points should appear close to be considered a group horizontally but they can appear anywhere to be considered part of a vertical band. Observe the large vertical band in the figure. So I am guessing I could just look for points that have the same x-coordinate (in this case, x=68) should give me a lot of points.

Other than this trivial solution, I can't think of anything smart that can be done here as this problem appears deceptively simple to me. Am I missing something here? Does this fall into some known class of problems and if so, is there a good and scalable approach to achieve this?

**Sample Dataset:**

```
1,23
1,23
2,23
3,23
4,23
5,23
6,23
7,23
8,23
9,23
10,23
11,23
12,23
13,23
14,23
15,23
16,23
10,33
11,33
12,33
13,33
14,33
15,33
16,33
17,33
18,33
19,33
2,28
2,28
3,28
34,75
34,76
34,76
34,77
34,78
34,79
34,80
34,81
34,82
34,83
34,75
34,76
34,76
34,77
34,78
34,79
34,80
34,81
400,28
400,28
400,28
68,200
68,201
68,203
68,204
68,100
68,101
68,103
68,104
```

Comment: Clustering algorithm could be interesting ?

Comment: You could try looking at the scipy.cluster module, though it looks like your system is a bit non-standard. Must the clusters be exclusively 1 row, 1 column, or are regions, e.g. (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) allowed?

Comment: Look at R-tree algorithm

Comment: @FredL: Actually, regions are allowed too except that it would be hard in my case to find out exactly how big a region is. I was trying to first get one-dimensional bands before heading the direction you pointed out.

Comment: @dziobas: Would you care to elaborate a bit on that? Do you mean, build an R-tree and then query it using all points to get spatially close neighbors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a little late, but this problem has been worrying me for some time.  I
was sure it could be solved with mixed integer / linear programming techniques
and asked for help in this question: [Identifying column and row clusters with linear programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137334/181772)

However, after getting a reply there, I had the insight that your problem, at
least as I understand it, is so simple (when framed as a constraint program)
that you can solve it trivially with a simple program (which you already
knew).  In other words, constraint programming would be a cool way to solve
this, but, at least with the approach I found, would give you the same answer
as something much simpler.

I'll explain below my reasoning, how I would implement it with a constraint
solving package, and then give the final, trivial, algorithm.

### Mixed integer programming solution

The most important detail is the difference between horizontal and vertical
groups.  As far as i can see, anything that aligns vertically can be in the
same group.  But horizontal groups are different - components have to be close
together.

The hardest part of solving a problem with constraints seems to be finding a
way to describe the limits in a way that the solver can understand.  I won't
go into the details here, but solvers are frustratingly limited.  Luckily I
think there is a way to do this here, and it is to consider horizontal
neighbours:  if there are N points in a row then we have `N-1` sets of
neighbours (for example, with 4 points A B C and D there are the three pairs
AB, BC, and CD).

For each pair, we can give a score, which is the number of spaces between them
(`S_i`) scaled by some factor `K`, and a flag (`F_i`) which is 0 or 1.  If the
pair are in the same horizontal group then we set the flag to 1, otherwise it
is zero.

It is critical to see that the set of flags for all the pairs *completely
defines a solution*.  We can run across any row, placing pairs with a flag
of 1 in the same horizontal group, and starting a new horizontal group each
time the flag is 0.  Then, we can take all horizontal groups of size 1 and
convert them into vertical groups: any point that is not in a horizontal group
must be in a vertical group (even if it is a vertical group of just one).

So all we need now is a way to express an optimal solution in terms of the
flags.  I suggest that we want to minimise:

```
sum(1 - F_i) + sum(K * S_i * F_i)
```

This has two terms.  The first is the sum of "one minus the flag" for each
pair.  The flag is 1 when the points are in the same horizontal group and 0
otherwise.  So minimising this value is the same as saying that we want as
*few* horizontal groups as possible.  If this was the only constraint then we
could set it to zero by making all the `F_i` 1 - by making all pairs on a row
members of the same group.

But the second term stops us from choosing such an extreme solution.  It
penalises groups with gaps.  If a pair are in the same group, but are
separated by `S_i` spaces, then we have a "penalty" of `K * S_i`.

So we have a trade-off.  We want horizontal groups, but we don't want gaps.
The final solution will depend on `K` - if it is large then we won't include
any spaces in horizontal groups.  But as it is decreased we will start to do
so, until when it is very small (tends to zero) we place everything in a row
in a single group.

To use this you would choose some `K`, calculate the `S_i`, and enter the expression above into a constraint system.  The system would then choose `F_i` to minimise the expression.  Finally you would convert the `F_i` into a pattern of groups by scanning each row as described above and then grouping singletons vertically.

### Analytic solution

OK, cool.  At this point we have a way to express the problem that we can give
to a constraint engine.

But it's trivial to solve!  We don't need no stinkin' constraint engine to
solve this - we can just look at the expression:

```
sum(1 - F_i) + sum(K * S_i * F_i)
```

The two sums are over the same pairs, so we can move everything into the sum:

```
sum(1 - F_i + K * S_i * F_i)
sum(1 + F_i * (K * S_i - 1))
```

And then extract the constant (`N` here is the total number of pairs):

```
N + sum(F_i * (K * S_i - 1))
```

Now note that each term in the sum is independent (and additive).  So for each
term, we want the minimum value.  We have two options:

- if `F_i` is 0 then the entire term is 0.
- otherwise, `F_i` is 1 and the term is `K * S_i - 1`.

So the best choice depends on whether `K * S_i` is greater than 1.  If `K *
S_i` is greater than 1 then the smallest value of the term is 0, and `F_i`
should be 0.  Otherwise the second choice above is negative, and `F_i` should
be one.

### Trivial algorithm

What does this mean?  It means that for each pair we can simply look at the
number of spaces, `S_i`.  If that is greater than `1 / K` then the two points
should be in separate groups.  Otherwise they should be in the same group.

So all this fancy maths and optimisation and constraints and bullshitting
comes down to: how far apart are two points in neighbouring pairs?  If they
are closer than some cut-off, put them in the same horizontal group.
Otherwise, put them in separate groups.

So here, finally, is your algorithm:

```
choose some cut-off value, X
place each point in its own, singleton, horizontal group
for each row with more than one point:
    for each neighbouring pair in the row:
        if the space between the pair is less than X:
            join into a single horizontal group
for each column:
    join any remaining singleton groups into a single vertical group
```

### Conclusion

- You can use constraint programming techniques to solve this problem, but such techniques are restricted to solutions that describe the system in the "correct" (typically, linear) way.
- The simplest such approach I can find is equivalent to a trivial, direct
  algorithm that divides points in a row into horizontal groups depending on
  the number of spaces between them.
- This all depends on a whole pile of assumptions about what you wanted which may, of course,
  be over-simplifications, or just plain wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [cluster module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cluster/1.1.1b3#downloads). It contains implementation of K-means clustering algorithm. You can adjust argument of `getclusters` function to change the number of clusters you want.

```
s = '''
1,23
1,23
2,23
...
68,101
68,103
68,104
'''

from cluster import *

ll = [tuple(map(int,each.split(','))) for each in s.split()]

#horizontal 
cl = HierarchicalClustering(ll, lambda x,y: abs(x[0]-y[0]))

for c in cl.getlevel(1):
    print c

#vertical
cl = HierarchicalClustering(ll, lambda x,y: abs(x[1]-y[1]))

for c in cl.getlevel(1):
    print c
```

Comment: I don't think k-means clustering will return 1xn and nx1 clusters only which as I understand is OP's requirement.

Comment: @Abhinav I don't think that is his requirement. But let me read the question again. *Carefully* this time! :)

Comment: OP mentions horizontal bands and vertical bands so it looks like he is looking for a way to cluster in the points in bands only.

Comment: @Abhinav I have updated the answer according to your suggestions. Thanks! :)

Comment: Wonderful! As of now, it does give me what I want and have accepted it as a solution. I will provide an update if I find something else :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works for small datasets, even with a dataset of 1200 points, it just takes too long :( It just sits there in `c.getLevel(1)` and never returns.

Comment: Hmm... I have handled larger problems without PyPy so I am feeling a little uncomfortable avoiding the actual problem and choosing a workaround so early. Do you think it is the problem with the language? I am guessing it might have something to do with either the algorithm or the implementation of that algorithm. I guess I'll check the source once.

Comment: Problem must be with the algorithm only. I think @Suresh Venkat can help you.